# Using unfiltered search in MarkLogic

Tags: indexing, marklogic

Consider the following query:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace ts = "http://marklogic.com/MLU/top-songs";

let $range_query := cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("ts:week"), ">=", xs:date("2009-05-01"))
let $query := cts:search(fn:doc(), $range_query)
return $query/ts:top-song/ts:title/text()
```

(Not: Range index for week has been enabled)

I believe that the above query can give results based only on the indexes and with this assumption I made the following change:

```
let $query := cts:search(fn:doc(), $range_query, "unfiltered")
```

I got the same results.

However,

```
fn:count($query/ts:top-song/ts:title/text()) gave a result of 8
```

and

```
xdmp:estimate($query/ts:top-song/ts:title/text())
```

gave an error:Expression is unsearchable

I believe this means that the query cannot be searched using indexes. If so, why does the unfiltered approach work just fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unfiltered search works and the `xdmp:estimate` expression doesn't because they're not using the same query and expression. The query you pass `cts:search` is fully searchable, so it will work when you call `xdmp:estimate` on it:

```
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), $range_query, "unfiltered")
```

`xdmp:estimate` requires a "partially searchable" XPath expression, [which has a specific definition according to MarkLogic.](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/performance/query_meters#id_17135) There are some subtle details about what makes an expression fully or partially or not searchable, and probably the most instructive way to go about it is using `xdmp:query-trace` to test the expression.

Comment: I think you meant xdmp:estimate($query) should give me the answer. However, it still gives the error: Expression is unsearchable

Comment: @Yash, No, I didn't mean to copy the `let`. The variable reference is unsearchable. I updated the answer.

Comment: Assigning an expression to a variable causes it (the variable expression, not the search expression) to be unsearchable. 
A concept that was so non-intuitive that I went bald pulling my hair out the first dozen times I encountered this.   Possibly this has changed since I last went bald.